# Pyhton - Dataframe to_sql gives sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError

Tags: python, sql, python-imaging-library, pandas-to-sql

I have a code that reads metadata and it puts the information into a dataframe. That part works, I then use the `to_sql` function and I get this error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Unknown object type: IFDRational', 'HY000')`. My output shows everything that is in quotes besides what is an integer. Knowing SQL everything needs to be in the single quotes so I think that's that's my issue.

Here  is my script:

```
info_list = []
info_list2 = []
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    try:
        # read the image data using PIL
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

        # extract other basic metadata
        info_list.append([
        os.path.basename(image.filename),
        os.path.getsize(image.filename),
        image.info['dpi'][0],
        image.height,
        image.width,
        image.format,
        image.mode,
        getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
        ])
        Df1 = pd.DataFrame(info_list, columns=["FileName", "FileSize","DPI", "Height", "Width", "Format", "Mode", "Frames"])

    except:
        image = Image.open(os.path.join(rootdir, file))

        # extract other basic metadata
        info_list.append([
        os.path.basename(image.filename),
        os.path.getsize(image.filename),
        pathlib.Path(image.filename).suffix,
        image.height,
        image.width,
        image.format,
        image.mode,
        getattr(image, "n_frames", 1)
        ])
        Df2 = pd.DataFrame(info_list2, columns=["FileName","Format", "Mode"])

Df1.to_sql("SuspensiaImageDetails", con = engine, if_exists = 'append', dtype= NVARCHAR('50'))
Df2.to_sql("SuspensiaImageDetails", con = engine, if_exists = 'append', dtype= NVARCHAR('50'))
```

I think I have to convert everything to a string? or is there supposed to do something else to pust this into the SQL table.

Comment: Which database do you use. Do you try to fetch the result? Same [Error Code HY000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830862/12621346)